# Web workers - firefox vs. chromium (Chrome and MS Edge)

Tags: performance, google-chrome, firefox, web-worker

I'am developping a [fractal explorer](https://www.mandelbrotandco.com) in browser still in beta.
The general idea is to offer a navigation as fluid as possible.
I use of course **a pool of web workers** and split each image in n chunks where n is the number of available cpu (`navigator.hardwareConcurrency`).
Each worker calculates and posts back an ImageData.
It works great on chromium based navigators (ie Chrome and MS edge, both show roughly same performance). Safari is ok too.

On Firefox it's awful !

[image: bench chart]

The mean time calculation is surprisingly roughly x8 on Firefox, the number of CPU and workers on my computer. So I suspected Firefox to run workers concurrently and not in parallell, but this assumption should be wrong as far as the mean time calculation is decreasing proportionnaly with the number of active workers as the chart shows.

So.... Is there anybody with an idea / explanation ?

thanks :)

#### A weird hack-solution

Trying to simplify my code for publishing it as kindly requested (thanks again @Kaiido), I have found a solution... well, not really a solution, let's say it's more a hack !

Adding **anywhere** in the worker's message handler a blank `try {} catch {}` block the performance of Firefox is equivalent (and sometimes better :) than Chrome.

code is [here](https://github.com/raph-of-burgondy/web-worker-chrome-firefox)

Explanation ?

Comment: Maybe you could show a bit of what you are doing? Certainly v8 is able to optimize your code better than SpiderMonkey, but without seeing any line of code we won't be able to help you find how to make both happy. Also, beware that you should start *hardwareConcurrency - 1* Workers, otherwise one of these will fight with main thread.

Comment: Just had a quick look at your worker.js (you'd still have to include it directly in your question for it to be valid by our standards), and I see you are creating new ImageData objects everytime, and simply copying these through postMessage. That means that for every single chunk you are assigning 2 new ArrayBuffers, when you'd just need one such ArrayBuffer per Worker by transferring these instead of copying.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for your helps and my apologizes for not having included my code. Double thanks for having a look directly on the site :)). Regarding the number of workers , you are right. I will change that. But my tests show it has no influence on the performance. I have also changed my code to work with an arraybuffer which is now transferred to main thread (and not anymore copied). no significant performance improvement.

Comment: I appreciate your apologies, yet I would prefer if you actually did provide some coed in your question.

Comment: I opened https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1642067

Comment: cool :)) -  running your test-case.html on my computer, both cases are very close, roughly in range 190ms 195ms.with a very slight advantage to the try-catch.

Comment: Oh really? Then I messed up the test case... Can you check what would make it reproduce again on your machine? E.g does it happen only in webworkers? What OS are you on? Which version of FF? Can you try on an other device? For me it's 10 times slower on both my macOs and Andro phone.

Comment: oups  - sorry - your test-case is absolutly ok ! Too early in the morning and i have messed up everything.

Answer (score 0):

That *was* a bug in Firefox with their optimizer.
I did open [an issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1642067) to their bug tracker and it's now fixed in latest Nightly (79.0a1 (2020-06-04)).